# Click a button and open next url

Tags: javascript

I want to create a little script by buying something, so I don't have to do everything manually

This is the buy button;

```
jQuery.get('/en/add-to-cart/12345')
```

and now I want to open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) after adding the component to my card.

Could anyone explain what I should write exactly?

Comment: Please share your code where you add your component

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
$.get('/en/add-to-cart/12345',function() { location = 'https://www.google.com' })
```

or

```
$.get('/en/add-to-cart/12345',function() { window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank') })
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this

```
$.get('/en/add-to-cart/12345',function() { window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com' })
```